# How to cast a VBA String as Object type

Tags: vba, variables, type-conversion

I am programming VBA. An interface I need to use here accepts arguments only if they are type "object". To use it I need to fill a string like "abc" into that variable. This always brings something like typemismatch.

```
dim varName as Object 
Set varName = "My Text"
```

same  problem when running

```
dim varName as Object 
varName = "My Text"
```

I haven't found any conversion and have no idea how to solve

Comment: Why do you need it as an object?  Why does the signature only accept an object?

Comment: Can you perhaps provide more information about the overall goal here? You're attempting to store a string into an Object variable, which won't work (as you can see).  I'm curious as to what Interface you are trying to use that only accepts Objects, and what the end goal is.

Comment: I have referenced a library in Excel VBA. This features an API that is described in help:  Sub AddVariable(ByRef  VarName as System.Object,  ByRef Value as System.Object)

Comment: if I call that API with two arguments that were defined as "object" that sub does not bring error. However I need to put something reasonable into those two variables.

Comment: Have you tried simply passing the `String` instance?

Comment: if calling AddVariable ("bla 1", "blabla 2") it fails. When doing Dim temp1, temp2 as string, then temp1 = "bla"  temp2 = "blabal"  I can call AddVariable (temp1, temp2) without problems.

Comment: If assigning your variables works...why aren't you doing it that way?

Comment: Excellent, I'll write an answer with brief explanation. This is an interesting question, if not an uncommon one, but perhaps it will help others in the future :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like you're referencing a .NET library, in which case [`System.String`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string(v=vs.110).aspx) inherits from the generic [`System.Object`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-2). In other words, a `String` *is* a .NET `Object` -- no cast is necessary.

You *should* be able to pass a variable reference to the string, rather than trying to cast it to an `Object` type, which I don't think is possible in pure VBA.

```
Dim arg1 as String, arg2 as String
arg1 = "foo"
arg2 = "bar"
AddVariable(arg1, arg2)
```

Comment: I had a feeling .NET was involved somewhere; only thing that makes sense when assigning Object as the generic parameter.

Comment: Note that he cannot directly pass a string literal because the function accepts the arguments per reference

Comment: you right. The help I have focus on .net  rather than VBA

Answer (score 0):

try to use variant instead: pt your objects into a variant.
also do not use "set" with strings.